# frequency count for file column in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, count

I have a file with 8 columns using `|` as a delimiter and I want to count the occurence frequency of the words in the 8th column. I tried awk like this

```
awk -F '{print $8}' | sort | uniq -c $FILE
```

but I get instead a print of the whole file and I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT:** Now I get printed what I want as below:

```
1  
2307 Internet Explorer       
369 Safari  
2785 Chrome  
316 Opera  
4182 Firefox
```

but I can't understand where this "1" come from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just `awk` to do this:

```sh
awk -F '|' '{freq[$8]++} END{for (i in freq) print freq[i], i}' file
```

This awk command uses `|` as delimiter and uses an array `seen` with key as `$8`. When it finds a key `$8` increments the frequency (value) by `1`. 
Btw you need to add custom delimiter `|` in your command and use it like this:

```sh
awk -F '|' '{print $8}' file | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: this prints me the different occurencies in a list but I also want the number of times they appear in the column.

Comment: Sure you can see `awk -F '|' '{print $2}' file | sort | uniq -c` for that.

Comment: yes I found my mistake in the order of piping. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes `freq` is better name :)

Answer (score 2):

Among other things, you're running `uniq` on  `$FILE` instead of running `awk` on `$FILE` and piping the results to sort then uniq. You meant to write:

```
awk -F'|' '{print $8}' "$FILE" | sort | uniq -c
```

but all you need is one command:

```
awk -F'|' '{cnt[$8]++} END{for (key in cnt) print cnt[key], key}' "$FILE"
```

wrt `I can't understand where this "1" come from` - you have 1 empty $8 in your input file. Maybe a blank line. You can find it with:

```
awk -F'|' '$8~/^[[:space:]]*$/{print NR, "$0=<"$0">, $8=<"$8">"}' "$FILE"
```

Comment: aahh yes It's the first thing you said. Wrong order in the piping. Now it's all fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: you are right extra line from copy pasting thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

A `cut` based answer, (plus a bit of `sed` to surround items with quotes, the better to make blank lines visible):

```
cut -d'|' -f8 "$FILE" | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | sort | uniq -c
```