# count in column and result bash

Tags: bash, shell

i have a weird project

i have long file. its separated in columns by '|' and has a total of 8.
the 8th col. has browsers listed (chrome, I.E, safari etc).
i need to print them in alphabetical order, and **after** each one its users.
example :

```
Chrome 432
Safari 543
etc..
```

so far i have tried

```
grep -v "^#" < < file > | awk -F '|' '{ print $8 }' | sort | uniq -c
```

the `grep` to remove all `#`comments

the `awk` to get the 8th column

and then `sort` and `uniq` to 'print' the results

this is what i get :

```
2
2307 Internet Explorer
369 Safari
2785 Chrome
316 Opera
4182 Firefox
```

so i need firstly to get rid of that irrelevant '2' in the beggining (i think it must be blank line or something)

the script need to be "universal" so i cant use `grep -c "Chrome"` for example

if i try to run another `awk` after `uniq` the results get really messed up

`2
2785
4182x
2307net Explorer 
316 
369i`

lastly it seems to be a 9th column due to "Internet Explorer" how can i merge it with the 8th column?

p.s my biggest issue tho is to get the names first and the mumbers afterwards

p.s 2 i have checked this thread [frequency count for file column in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945363/frequency-count-for-file-column-in-bash) and i couldnt get the results i wanted

prortion of my file

`#id|lastName|firstName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed
1099511633435|Smith|Jack|male|1981-04-19|2010-05-26T03:45:11.772+0000|50.72.193.218|Internet Explorer
1099511635042|Kiss|Gyorgy|male|1984-09-14|2010-05-16T22:57:41.808+0000|91.137.244.86|Chrome
1099511635218|Law-Yone|Eric|male|1987-01-20|2010-05-26T20:10:22.515+0000|203.81.95.235|Chrome
1099511638444|Jasani|Chris|female|1981-05-22|2010-04-29T20:50:40.375+0000|196.223.11.62|Firefox
2199023256615|Arbelaez|Gustavo|male|1986-11-02|2010-07-17T18:53:47.633+0000|190.96.218.101|Chrome`

Comment: sorry I messed up the edit before, but I don't see why you have `grep -v '#' < < file` (two `<` chars).  You'll need to include a very small version of `file` in your Q so we can experiment to see why you get the `2` and to simplify other testing. You're almost there. Read about `"$1"` (or `"$@"`) in shell scripting. Good luck.

Comment: i mean `grep -v '#' file.txt`

Comment: by < file > i mean just a file dont worry.
my input is grep -v '#' file.txt

Comment: I don't understand where all these 432 and 543 from the top of the question come from. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: its the browser's name along with the people used it(just an example of the output format i am looking for)

Comment: I think your messed output may be because of endline characters in the input. Run `dos2unix` on your input file (NB: it will rewrite it! If you want a copy save a backup or use `dos2unix -n oldfile newfile`!) and try AFAbyss's answer again. If that works I'll explain why.

Comment: (Actually decided to go with a full answer anyway.)

Comment: "lastly it seems to be a 9th column due to "Internet Explorer" how can i merge it with the 8th column?": It's not a 9th column. You are instructing `awk` to take `|` as the column separator, so it will not accept a space. There's no `|` in `Internet Explorer` so it's all within one column.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
grep -v "^#" file | awk -F'|' '{print$8}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print$2,$3,$1}'
```

Comment: well already tried that..check my post to see the result i get(just added it)

Comment: @PantelosPapado If I run this command on your test data it works fine. Please try with that file, and if it works, check whether the rest of your full records indeed keeps the same format everywhere.

Comment: Here's what it says, copied verbatim from the answer with data copied and pasted from your question: `Firefox  1 (newline)
Chrome  3 (newline)
Internet Explorer 1`

Answer (score 0):

You've got all the steps right up to here, the problem to swap the names and the numbers is generally a simple extension of the pipe by another `awk '{print$2,$3,$1}'` (as suggested by AFAbyss, credits to them!) or by `sed -s "s/^\s\+\([0-9]\+\) \(.*\)$/\2 \1/"` (which says: find a sequence of digits followed by a space and an arbitrary string up to the end of line, output the latter, a space, and the former, and has the slight advantage of not treating "Internet Explorer" as two fields, and *not expecting that no browser name will have at most two words*). This should work, why doesn't it? It's quite disquieting that your lines come out so different from the expectation!

### The problem is deeper

So the problem why your output is mangled is elsewhere, and I am almost sure it's the end-of-line format. Note that in different systems the end of line is marked by different characters or character combinations:

```
LF (\n, \012) on Unices,
CR (\r, \015) on classic Macs,
CRLF (\r\n, \015\012) on Windows
```

([heavily simplified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)). If your file is in Microsoft Windows format, Unix will read the `\r` as part of the line! Let's see what happens in a typical line:

```
...|196.223.11.62|Firefox\r\n
                  =========
                  field 8
```

This will happen in all lines containing `Firefox` (because it's always the last item and thus there's always an `\r\n` after it), so `sort` and `uniq` will do their job just fine, telling you that `Firefox\r` appears 4182 times:

```
4182 Firefox\r\n
==== =========**
cnt  output   EOL
```

**This is an invisible problem.** What `\r` does is *carriage return*, it will return your cursor to the beginning of the line. The following `\n` advances to the next line. Think typewriters: push all the way to the right, then pull the handle. In electronic typewriters it's just a NL key press and that's why Unix records it as such, the `\r` is now superfluous but it doesn't break the output if it's just before the `\n`.

But now when you try to swap the two parts of the line:

```
Firefox\r 4182\n
========= ====**
output    cnt EOL
```

And this is a disaster. `Firefox` gets printed, then the carriage returns to the leftmost column, then `4182` is printed **rewriting what's been typed before**. There are actually two blanks before the number because you instructed `awk` to print `$2`, then `$3` (empty), then `$1`, and `awk` inserts a space between each two. You'll get

```
Firefox\r   (field $2 is printed, resulting in the carriage returned to left)
↑
␣irefox\r   (space between $2 and $3)
 ↑
␣irefox\r   (field $3 is printed)
 ↑
␣␣refox\r   (space between $3 and $1)
  ↑
␣␣4812x\r   (field $1 is printed)
      ↑
```

and then a line feed. This is not a bug, it's a feature commonly used in programs which are interested in rewriting the last line without having to output a new line each time (`mplayer`, `wget`, ...). The bug is to have an extra `\r` at the end of the input line.

### How to fix it?

One way is to run your whole input through `dos2unix` which converts any occurences of `\r\n` to `\n`. But this is not necessary. If you went with my `sed` alternative, just tell it to stop before the `\r` instead of the `\n` (`$`) in the regex:

```
grep -v \# file \
  | cut -d \| -f 8 \
  | sort \
  | uniq -c \
  | sed -s "s/^\s\+\([0-9]\+\) \(.*\)\r/\2 \1/"
                                     ↑↑
```